# How do I debug existing C programs with Visual Studio 2010 Professional?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

how can I use the Visual Studio Debugger on existing C programs I found in a textbook? I want to debug these little examples one by one, but without the overhead of creating a full project for each example.

Example: Let's say I compile "helloworld.c" from the Visual Studio command prompt ("cl.exe helloworld.c"). This gives me helloworld.obj and helloworld.exe. I would like to know if there is a way to use the VS debugger on "helloworld.exe". So far, I have only worked with the debugger on full-blown projects; I have no idea how to debug small "stand-alone" test programs without the Visual Studio project overhead. (I hope this is not a dumb question, as the VS Debugger might only be available for the full project.)

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: What's wrong with a few `printf`s judiciously applied throughout the code?

Comment: Can't you just create one VS project and then overwrite the source code every time you want to debug a different small program?

Comment: @pmj:  There is plenty wrong with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you create one project for testing the sample codes? You can create a single .c-file for all the samples. This would look something like

```
void sampleA()
{
 //hello world
}

void sampleB()
{
 //hello everybody else
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//  sampleA(); 
  sampleB();
}
```

Comment: Here's what I did, if anyone runs into the same problem: 

- Create empty Visual C++ project
- Copy *.h and *.c files into project directory
- Add one (!) source file ("foo.c") with Solution Explorer > Source Files > Add > Existing Item
- Add command line parameters to project with Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments
- Set breakpoints, press F5 and debug away
- Replace source file "foo.c" with next example "bar.c" - since "bar.c" will also have a main() function, you have to remove "foo.c" from source files in order to avoid conflict.
- Rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

What I do when I have to use VS is to reuse the **plain.c project** I created a long time ago.

Just paste new code there and go. Throw the code in another file if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not impossible, but you'll have to learn a lot more about how to *exactly* build a program from the command line to get the best debugging experience.  There are a bunch of options that are real time savers and greatly improve the odds that you'll discover bugs.

Which is a little beside the point right now, learn C instead of spending time learning a boring tool with *way* too many options.  Creating a new project takes 5 seconds after a wee bit of practice.  Use the Win32 Console Application project template.

One small setting you have to change if you want to compile as C instead of C++.  Right-click the project, Properties, C/C++, Advanced, Compile As = Compile as C Code.

Comment: You normally don't need to set "Compile as C code" manually. If you have a *.c file, it is compiled as C code, while a *.cpp file is compiled as C++.

Comment: Precompiled header support enabled by the template requires more than one change, the option change is easiest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're set on not using projects then you can do this.  It just gets more difficult as the number of code files increases.

First, to do any meaningful source-level debugging, you will need to generate debug symbols.  Add the "/Zi" switch to your `cl.exe` command line:

```
cl.exe /Zi helloworld.c
```

This will generate `helloworld.exe`, `helloworld.obj`, and `helloworld.pdb` (these are the debugging symbols).

Next you will open Visual Studio 2010.  Use File -> Open -> File... and select `helloworld.exe`.  It will generate a wrapping solution with one project for your EXE file.

In Solution Explorer, right click on the EXE file and select Debug -> Step Into new instance.

It should pop up a source window and show you the first line of your program.  Now, debug away!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. The files are generated, including the pdb file. However, when I use File -> Open -> File... and select helloworld.exe, Visual Studio says: "Cannot enumerate resources in the executable." What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to choose Debug->Attach to process to your running exe.

Comment: @Daniel Rose, it's not necessary to attach to the process, although that could work too.  @Rainer, are you using a Visual Studio Command Prompt to invoke cl.exe? It's possible there is some mismatch somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger is part of Visual Studio, so you'll have to start it up anyway. However, for the debugger to work properly with your source code, you need to also generate a PDB file (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1.aspx)). You get this by including `/Zi` or `/ZI` as argument to cl.exe (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, just tried that. I get "Cannot enumerate resources in the executable." (See next answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

The "overhead" is hardly more effort that it took to post this question!

Simply start with the "Empty Project" template and add the single source file you wish to debug by right-clicking on the project browser sources folder.  It takes mere seconds.